# Proxy aplly for method dont't call

Tags: javascript

I want to have getter for initialize method of object

```
    var phas = new Proxy({b:9,
            cont:0,
            statistic:function(){
                console.log(this.cont)
                this.cont++
                }
            }, {
                has: function (target, key) {
                    if (key == "a") return false;
                    return true;
                },


                apply: function () {
                    console.log('run call ')
                }
            }
    )

phas.run();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: phas.run is not a function

manual for proxy object https://www.xul.fr/javascript/proxy.php

Comment: why use `run()` function is not there in your code? and linked page  also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood how proxies work.

When you create a proxy, you create a proxy on that object. The proxy will not automatically extend itself to the object's properties.

The `apply` trap is only applicable on functions, if you proxied a function, and then called it, it would work as you expect.

If you want to create methods dynamically, you will need to do something like this instead:

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        // If the property exists, just return it
        if (prop in target) 
            return target[prop];
        // Otherwise, return a function
        return function() { console.log("Some method", prop); };
    }
});

p.run() //Logs: Some method run
typeof p.a == 'function' // true
```